# Reconciling RGeo spheroid calculations with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, ruby

I have a Rails/Postgresql app that uses a combination of RGeo and PostGIS, and I'd like to move more calculations in to RGeo and reduce some of the load on the database. One of the problems I'm having is doing length calculations on the spheroid instead of the sphere. From the RGeo::Geographic docs (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rgeo/rgeo/RGeo/Geographic):

> Some geographic implementations include a secondary factory  that
>   represents a projection. For these implementations,  you can quickly
>   transform data between lat/long coordinates  and the projected
>   coordinate system, and most calculations  are done in the projected
>   coordinate system. For  implementations that do not include this
>   secondary projection  factory, calculations are done on the sphereoid.

There are three ways to make factories in RGeo::Geographic:

- `RGeo::Geographic.projected_factory`, which lets me include a factory for an arbitrary Proj4 projection
- `RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory`, which includes a factory for the SRID: 3857 projection
- `RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory`, which does not include a projection factory but explicitly does calculations on a spherical Earth.

The first two of those include a projection, so according to the docs calculations are done in that projection. The last one doesn't include a projection, but is specifically done on a spherical Earth. So it's unclear how to do calculations on the spheroid.

Ultimately, the thing I'm really trying to reconcile is the results of calculating the length of a linestring in RGeo with the results from calculating the length of a *geography* type linestring PostGIS.

If I have the following linestring:

```
LINESTRING(2.3565473 48.8518338,2.3566331 48.851804,2.3580518 48.8512945,2.3580839 48.851283,2.3581316 48.8512659,2.3589446 48.8509735,2.35903847509631 48.8509397089643)
```

Calculating its length in PostGIS:

- On the sphere: `select st_length(way,false)` = 207.625186169259 m
- On the spheroid: `select st_length(way,true)` = 208.114332509536 m

Calculating it in RGeo:

- On the sphere: `RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory.parse_wkt(way).length` = 207.85748843579324 m
- On the spheroid: ?

I understand that these differences are small, but I'd like to be consistent, at the very least for writing tests, and because I am going to be using both RGeo and PostGIS and don't want "errors" accumulating between them. The length of these linestrings is important.

Is it possible to get these values to be the same (/ do calculations on the spheroid in RGeo) or just an inevitable result of implementation differences?